# Javascript transformar un array creado a partir de inputs checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Tengo múltiples `input checkbox` creados desde un modelo con angular y ng-repeat, cuando selecciono algunos de ello obtengo esto, por ejemplo:

```
var accounts: [{'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}, {'AA234': false}, {'AA553': true}, {'AA7365': false}];
```

Pero la estructura que necesito manipular en el `controller` donde llamo un servicio de REST API es de esta forma:

```
var accounts: ['AA764', 'AA324', 'AA553'];
```

Solo trayendo la clave de los que están seleccionado, he intentado con la función de `javascript` `foreach` pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. ¿Existe algún servicio de Angular o librería externa que me pueda ayudar con esta transformación? Gracias.

Comment: estas seguro que tiene ese formato el array ? lo veo algo extraño quizas si fuera  var accounts: [ {'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}] como que le faltan las llaves

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo corrgí. Gracias,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrias usar algo como esto

```js
var accounts= [{'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}, {'AA234': false}, {'AA553': true}, {'AA7365': false}];

var result = _.map(accounts, function(item, index){
 return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item);
});

console.log(result.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Para implementar la iteracion entre los items de la lista me gusta usar la funcionalidad de la librería

[underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)

aunque esto es opcional podrias iterar de otra forma si lo crees conveniente.

Aunque el truco esta en el uso de [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

Comment: Te olvidaste de filtrar aquellos que tienen como valor `true`.

Answer (score 0):

El tema está en que tienes un arreglo de objetos donde el `value` de tu `<input type="checkbox" />` es una llave y el valor es si el objeto está marcado o no. Esto se convierte en un problema puesto que como es un objeto no se puede acceder a sus propiedades como si fuese un arreglo. Para ello, se deben utilizar artificios como el que se muestra a continuación.

Utilizando JavaScript puro y el paradigma funcional:

```js
var accounts = [{'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}, {'AA234': false}, {'AA553': true}, {'AA7365': false}];
var validKeys = accounts
    .filter(x => { var first; for (first in x) break; return x[first]; } )
    .map(x => { var first; for (first in x) break; return first; } );
alert(validKeys);
```

Si utilizas navegadores que soportan JavaScript JS 1.8.5 o superior, el código se reduce a:

```js
var accounts = [{'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}, {'AA234': false}, {'AA553': true}, {'AA7365': false}];
var validKeys = accounts
    .filter(x => x[Object.keys(x)[0]])
    .map(x => Object.keys(x)[0] );
alert(validKeys);
```

Respuesta basada en [Javascript: Getting the first index of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909003/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las funciones nativas de los arreglos en **javascript** (`filter`y `map`) para filtrar primero los seleccionados y luego obtener únicamente el identificador.

```
// Tu colección
var accounts = [{'AA764':true}, {'AA324': true}, {'AA234': false}, {'AA553': true}, {'AA7365': false}];

// Se obtienen solo los elementos con valor true
var selected = accounts.filter(function(item){
    return item[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item)];
});

// Se obtiene el arreglo únicamente con los identificadores
var selectedIDs = account.map(function(item){
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item);
});
```